# Использование директивы !important при установке стилей элементу при помощи свойства cssText

Tags: javascript, css

Необходимо присвоить некоторые обязательные стили только что созданному при помощи JavaScript элементу `elem`. Поскольку эти свойства являются совершенно обязательными и ни коим образом нельзя допустить их переопределения, было решено воспользоваться директивой `!important`.

```
elem.style.color = "red !important";
```

Однако так ничего не получается. Порывшись в интернете обнаружил, что установить `!important` свойство можно только через свойство `cssText` (ну или же через `setAtribute`).

```
elem.style.cssText = "color: red !important;";
```

Так, вроде бы, действительно работает. Однако я не понимаю, почему после такой установки возможно переопределить значение свойства:

```
elem.style.color = "green"; // работает! Текст действительно становится зеленым. Хотя, по идее, не должен.
```

Более того, мне непонятно, почему даже при отсутствии `!important` свойство не удается переопределить в `.css` файле.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("#test");

elem.style.color = "red";
```

```css
#test {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Hello</div>
```

Прошу объяснений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что если вы делаете так

```js
elem = document.getElementById("id1");
elem.style.color = "green";
```

```html
<div id="id1">hallow</div>
```

То цвет записывается в `inner style` элемента.
Запускаем, жмём `F12` и смотрим что получилось.

```
<div id="id1" style="color: green;">hallow</div>
```

А `inner style` всегда имеет наивысший приоритет, и никаким классовым переопределениям не подвержен. Кроме как если у класса установлен `important`.

```css
.class1 {
  color: red;
}

.class2 {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1" style="color:green">Привет</div>
<div class="class2" style="color:green">Привет</div>
```

Comment: Ааа! Точно! Совсем из головы вылетело. Тогда, выходит, и `!important` не нужен совершенно...

Comment: А что насчет этого: *Однако я не понимаю, почему после такой установки возможно переопределить значение свойства*?

Comment: @smellyshovel переопределение возможно либо через класс с important, в этом случае используйте ответ Кирилла. Либо через JS, в этом случае `inner style` перезапишется.

Comment: *в этом случае inner style перезапишется* - ну это я вижу. Спрашивал, почему. Ладно, в любом случае спасибо.

Comment: @smellyshovel Я не понял ваш вопрос, что почему, поясните пожалуйста?

Comment: @smellyshovel если стили так вот выставлять через JS, то они ставятся `inner style`, после этого уже всё работает по правилам `HTML` и `CSS`

Answer (score 3):

```
elem.style.setProperty("color", "red", "important");
```

[setProperty](http://setProperty)

Несколько свойств сразу:

```
elem.setAttribute("style", "color:red!important;font-size:20px!important");
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не знал о существовании такого API. Однако конкретно в моем случае не подойдет, поскольку мне нужно сразу несколько свойств устанавливать. Но все равно буду иметь в виду.